# Entity Framework doesn't recognise methods like Add, Remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework on ASP.NET MVC3 with Visual Studio 2010 and I have a problem: after I changed the database and moved the project from one computer to another, I no longer recognize the methods of `DbContext` such as `Add`, `Remove`, and not know how to reproduce them.

Mention that this code worked on another computer. I did not do nothing relevant changes on database for this model.

On the following example, `db` is `DbContext` and `TMSEntities` is name of instance.

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
        //
        // GET: /Category/
        private TMSEntities db = new TMSEntities();

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddCategory(Category model)
        {
            bool Success = true;
            string Status = string.Empty;
            Category item = new Category();
            item.Name = model.Name.Trim();
            item.Description = model.Description;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Name))
            {
                Success = false;
                Status += "Category name can not be empty! <br />";
            }

            var duplicate = db.Categories.Where(a => a.Name == item.Name).Count();

            if (duplicate > 0)
            {
                Success = false;
                Status += "Name already exists! <br />";
            }

            if (Success)
            {
                db.Categories.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Json(new { Success = Success, Status = Status });
            }
            else
            {
                return Json(new { Success = Success, Status = Status });
            }
        }
}
```

And after, my error is such as:

> 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' does not contain a definition for 'Add' and no extension method 'Add' accepting a first argument of type
>
> 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: check all the refrences

Comment: References are set. Other methods are recognized.

Comment: That's because ObjectSet doesn't have an Add method.  I have no idea why you would even have anything that's an ObjectSet if you're using a DbContext, since they should be DbSet's.

Comment: Erik, it is true but how can resolve it ?

Comment: In which assembly is `TMSEntities`? I think the reference is to an old version of the dll or the project on the other computer.

Comment: We can see the 'what' of what is happening, but the specifics of what is going on in your case appear likely to be too localized for a general answer to be helpful.

Comment: The name "TMSEntities" is default and comes from my local database name "TMS"/

Answer (score 1):

instead of using .Add() you use .AddObject() and instead of using .Remove you use .DeleteObject()... beacause

The reason that worked is because you declared the Context using Object content and no DBContext. DBContext is wrapper on ObjectContext. Much easier to use. Somehow your exercise has mixed the 2 up. When creating the Model and Content in the place, if teh right project type is used and the Lastest nuget packages are in, you should get a T4 (template that generates code) that uses DBContext. The code you above is for accessing a context derived from DBContext. Suggest you take a close look at Your Context def and Regenerate it. Highly recommend that your move to DBcontext

Comment: I don't need to use just Add / AddObject, I need methods like Find, Entry , to use LINQ , and more ... I can not rewrite all my project.